# How to add items from datatable to list in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a `web service method`, where i have to add items in list from `data-table`. How to do this? Here i am pasting my code. I am getting error in `items.Add(row)`.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<SelectUsers> GetUsers()
{
    List<SelectUsers> items = new List<SelectUsers>();

    DataTable DetailsTbl = new DataTable();
    int gimId = 0;
    if (DetailsTbl.Rows[0]["RwId"] != "")
    {
        gimId = Convert.ToInt32(DetailsTbl.Rows[0]["RwId"]);

    }  
    DataTable dtAssignTo = SLAFacadeBLL.GetGIMIncidentUsers(gimId);
    if (dtAssignTo != null && dtAssignTo.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dtAssignTo.Rows)
        {
            items.Add(row);
        }
        return items;
    }                
}
```

SelectUsers.cs:

```
public class SelectUsers
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone give any suggestion?

Comment: Can you add the code of `SelectUsers` class?

Comment: This is a class file only get and set method

Comment: I know, but I need to know the property names of `SelectUsers` class, you can't add a `DataRow` to a `List<SelectUsers>`

Comment: I have added now..just have look on my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a `DataRow` to a `List<SelectUsers>`, you have to assign the values from `row` to a `SelectUsers`. As per comment below, `Value` is taken from `row["Id"]` and `Text` is taken from `row["Name"]`, so this code should work

```
if (dtAssignTo != null && dtAssignTo.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dtAssignTo.Rows)
    {
        items.Add(new SelectUsers { Value = row["Id"].ToString(), Text = row["Name"].ToString() });
    }
}
return items;
```

and you should move `return items;` to outside of `if (dtAssignTo != null && dtAssignTo.Rows.Count > 0)` block to avoid `not all code paths return a value` error.

Comment: Thnaks...but again it is showing error in GetUsers() method....the error is GetUser() method -not all code paths return a value.

Comment: What's the error? Can you tell me the column names of `row` and which columns will be taken for `SelectUsers`? I'm only assuming the column names are `Value` and `Text`.

Comment: Okie..in palce of "Value" and "Text".we have to put the column name.Thanks

Comment: Yes exactly, if you can tell me the column names I will change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

public static List GetUsers()
    {
        List items = new List();

```
    DataTable DetailsTbl = new DataTable();
    int gimId = 0;
    if (DetailsTbl.Rows[0]["RwId"] != "")
    {
        gimId = Convert.ToInt32(DetailsTbl.Rows[0]["RwId"]);

    }
    DataTable dtAssignTo = SLAFacadeBLL.GetGIMIncidentUsers(gimId);
    if (dtAssignTo != null && dtAssignTo.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        foreach (DataRow row in dtAssignTo.Rows)
        {
            SelectUsers selectuser = new SelectUsers();
            selectuser.Value = row["Value"].ToString(); // row["column name in the datatable"].ToString();
            selectuser.Text = row["Text "].ToString();  // row["column name in the datatable"].ToString();
            items.Add(selectuser);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.